# XSLT Pattern Matching for Config Transform

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, web-config-transform

I'm trying to do Config transform.
In a config file I have

```html
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
    <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/someservice" ....../>
</client>
```

I need to replace 'localhost' using XSLT transform. I cant get my way around using regex.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity transform and add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="@address[contains(., '://localhost/')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'localhost')" />
    <xsl:text>replacement value</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'localhost')" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible in XSLT to do substitution for eg. connection string I might put !(#SERVER#), !(#HOST#) and then transform gets value from another xml (this bit I'm able to do!). Like in C#, I could do regex, read the key get the value and replace for output xml. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="endpoint/@address">
        <xsl:attribute name="address"><xsl:value-of select="replace(current(),'localhost','www.myhost.com')"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Take note  that your Input XML file must be well formed. It must have a root XML node that contains all other nodes. See my test source XML below. I chose to name the root node "xml". And the node "system.serviceModel" must have a closing tag.

Source XML:

```
<xml>
   <system.serviceModel/>
   <client>
      <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/someservice"/>
   </client>
</xml>
```

Result XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
   <system.serviceModel/>
   <client>
      <endpoint address="net.pipe://www.myhost.com/someservice"/>
   </client>
</xml>
```

Comment: XSLT/XPath 1.0 has no `replace()` function.